# Licensing a Project that contains Others' Works

Tags: copyright, licensing, software

Right now, I'm making a video game that uses another's font. I want to make absolutely clear that this is font is not made by me. Can I say so in a different file (say, `fonts/the-fonts-i-didnt-make/README.txt`), or do I have to include it in the license file I have now, `./LICENSE.txt`?

**Additional Information**

- The current license I use is Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0
- The font I want to use is called "DS-Digital", and is marked as shareware.
- [I found the font here](http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font), including its license.

Comment: You need to find the licensing terms of the font; "shareware" does not indicate what rights are being licensed. From http://www.dafont.com/faq.php#copyright: "The fonts presented on this website are their authors' property, and are either freeware, shareware, demo versions or public domain. The licence mentioned above the download button is just an indication. Please look at the readme-files in the archives or check the indicated author's website for details, and contact him if in doubt. If no author/licence is indicated that's because we don't have information, that doesn't mean it's free."

Comment: @apsillers I gave a link to where the fonts/license is, as well as giving a brief description of it in the actual question. I didn't see anything in the license on how I can package ti in my own project.

Comment: Absent any permission to use the font in derivative works, you cannot use it in your project. Such permission may be given by the author somewhere, but right now I don't see where.